# Where to find USER_ID/OWNER_NAME for ids parameter of YouTube Analytics API

Tags: youtube-api

The YouTube Analytics API docs (https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/index#Parameters) specify either:

channel==USER_ID

or

contentOwner==OWNER_NAME

Should be set as the ids parameter for requesting reports.

My questions is, is there an API method I can call to retrieve the value for USER_ID or OWNER_ID values as I am currently struggling to find what these are?

Or if not, where else can I locate these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, you're going to want to run channel-level reports, not content owner reports (unless you specifically know that you have access to content owner reports).

The value to use in the `channel==` parameter is the channel id of the currently authorized channel. There's some [information in the docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/channel_reports#Overview) about how to obtain the currently authorized channel's id using `youtube.channels.list(part="id", mine=true)`. This is also illustrated in the [sample code](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/code_samples/python).